# Docker Compose doesn't work when I have "volumes", otherwise it works. Why?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The following **docker-compose.yml** works:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_db:
    container_name: my_db
    image: postgres
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=ArborMetrix
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=753951456852
#    volumes:
#      - type: volume
#        source: my_db_volume
#        target: /my_project
  web_app:
    container_name: web_app
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
                      python manage.py migrate &&
                      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
#    volumes:
#      - type: volume
#        source: web_app_volume
#        target: /my_project
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - my_db

#volumes:
#  my_db_volume:
#  web_app_volume:
```

When I un-comment the comments above to implement the volumes, I get the following error:

```
Starting my_db ... done
Starting web_app ... done
Attaching to my_db, web_app
my_db      |
my_db      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
my_db      |
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.281 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.282 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.283 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.314 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.448 UTC [25] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-06-26 18:46:48 UTC
my_db      | 2020-06-26 18:47:07.484 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_app    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
web_app    |     self.connect()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
web_app    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
web_app    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_app    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_app    | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_app    |    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_app    |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_app    |
web_app    |
web_app    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_app    |
web_app    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_app    |   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
web_app    |     main()
web_app    |   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
web_app    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
web_app    |     utility.execute()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
web_app    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
web_app    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
web_app    |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
web_app    |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
web_app    |     loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
web_app    |     applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
web_app    |     if self.has_table():
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
web_app    |     return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
web_app    |     return self._cursor()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
web_app    |     self.ensure_connection()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
web_app    |     self.connect()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_app    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
web_app    |     self.connect()
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
web_app    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_app    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
web_app    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_app    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_app    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_app    |    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_app    |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_app    |
web_app exited with code 1
```

**References:**

In **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

RUN mkdir /my_project

WORKDIR /my_project

COPY . /my_project

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In **settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "ArborMetrix",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "753951456852",
        "HOST": "my_db",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason, your volumes? You are getting a `could not connect to server: Connection refused ` It means your app can't run queries because they can't connect to the DB. Here another section of your log:  `Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_app    |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: The volume for web_app is overwriting the working directory /my_project with a named volume. Are you sure that what you don’t want to mount your local directory instead?

Comment: Are you sure you want to mount anything at all?  If you delete `volumes:` as you have, then you're running the code that's being built into the image, which is frequently what you want.

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for the hint Iain, I have fixed the issue. I will post my solution.

Comment: @DavidMaze I heard database services need a volume to persist data across repeated container openings. Is this not true?

Comment: It is; `my_db` should probably have a volume (not your application source tree) mounted on `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

I put the volume in the same directory as the one containing all the source code for web_app.

Fellow user [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) commented,

> The volume for web_app is overwriting the working directory
> /my_project with a named volume.

I didn't know volumes overwrites the ENTIRE directory for itself (selfish!).

**Solution:**

I changed the target to an empty directory in the container.

`target: /my_project/my_db_volume`

`target: /my_project/web_app_volume`